Synthesis of polypropylene
So, I have two questions regarding the synthesis of polypropylene:

I have tried looking everywhere but couldn't find a detailed mechanism for the termination step of the synthesis of polypropylene (isotactic and syndiotactic) using the Ziegler-Natta catalysis.

I couldn't find anywhere what are the end groups of polypropylene. I read in some books that they can be either isopropyl or vinyl, but I want a solid source to explain how I determine the identity of the end groups of the polymeric chain, once the polymerization is finished.


thanks in advance

"In a previous paper we have demonstrated the presence of isopropyl end groups at both ends of isotactic polypropylene chains obtained by using suitable methyl derivatives or organo-metallic cocatalysts. "

thank you! It helps me a lot
